# How to use bind:prop-like feature over Svelte constructor

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to start using Svelte into an old app that is built by something else.

I created MyInput.svelte.

```html
<!-- MyInput.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  export let text: string;
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={text} />
```

```html
<!-- a parent component -->
<MyInput bind:text={parentText} />
<p>text: {parentText}</p>
```

I use the component from vanilla JS.

```js
let parentText = "";
component = new MyInput({
  props: { text: parentText },
  target: el,
});
```

The above code gives an initial value to the prop `text`. Is there a way to detect the value got update inside so that I can reflect it to the variable `parentText`? I wish there were something like `component.$watch()` for it

If there were open issues about this, like [slot feature](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2588), I'd like to hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be handy if there was a way to tie into the bound props, but I can't seem to find it in the docs

You can get around that though using the [event dispatcher](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher)

You can then use `$on` to listen to events.

example:

```js
let parentText = "";
const st = new MyInput({
  props: { text: parentText },
  target: el,
});

st.$on("text", (event) => {console.log(event.detail)})
```

in the component  you can then add a listener that triggers the change

```js
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

$: dispatch("text", text);
```

Comment: Reactive statement can be simplified to just `$: dispatch("text", text);`.